# gcloud stop working - "was unexpected at this time."

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

I just update my google cloud SDK on windows 10 (gcloud components update).
After the update the gcloud command stop working.
All I get is (for example : gcloud -h):
PATH\lib\gcloud.py" -h" was unexpected at this time.

I try to re-install but it didn't help:(

[image]

Comment: I seem to be having a similar issue except I appear to be getting a message of `\Google\Cloud was unexpected at this time.` for every command. Unfortunately, this also means I cannot revert to a previous version

Comment: Seems like this a bug in latest edition, since it just was reported and at least us experienced this

Comment: I was having the same issue today because I just recently updated as well, I'm using the Git bash terminal (http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download) for now, it works.

Comment: The script `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\gcloud.cmd` if broken. The problem is at the very bottom of the file in the last `ELSE` block. The script is also breaking the PATH environment variable on Windows. Download a version 2.73 https://storage.cloud.google.com/cloud-sdk-release

Comment: was having same issue (\Google\Cloud was unexpected at this time) - version 2.73 worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue that is being tracked [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/146458519)

After hours of trying to fix it! I found how :)

1. uninstall google SDK
2. https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/google-cloud-sdk.zip
3. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-interactive#interactive_installation

This fix the bug.

After that I had new bug in pyCharm GAE:

ImportError: No module named _subprocess

I fix this with the solution here:
[Error importing built-in module "_subprocess" using Google Cloud Platform's Local Development Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59311533/error-importing-built-in-module-subprocess-using-google-cloud-platforms-loca)

Hope this helps and saves a lot of trouble for you guys :)

Answer (score 4):

As noted in the other answers, this is a bug with the 274.0.0 version of gcloud. [Another report of this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/146658630) actually identifies where the bug is and offers this fix:

> If you are stuck and need an immediate solution, here's a workaround that will move you forward, but you should reinstall the Cloud SDK from scratch when a fix is ready.
>
> 1. Open `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk-bin\gcloud.cmd` in your editor
> 2. Near line 170, change `) ELSE (` to be just `)`
> 3. Remove the `)` on the last line in the file.

That should get you working in the short term (albeit with an extraneous error message every time you run a command). After getting it working you can revert to version 273.0.0 (so that you stop getting the error message and aren't using a modified version) using:

```
gcloud components update --version=273.0.0
```

Comment: `where gcloud` is useful to do if that's not the precise directory of `gcloud.cmd`

Answer (score 4):

This is being tracked in the public bug https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/146458519

We have a patch for two files that are causing these problems.  These apply in two cases (both on Windows):
1.  A new install fails, or
2.  You are unable to run gcloud after performing a components update.

For case # 1, please download the attached file  install.bat, and copy it to the location where you have attempted to install gcloud, e.g. C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk.  Then run it, e.g.

> cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk
>   .\install.bat

For both cases #1 and #2, download the attached file gcloud.cmd, and copy it to the bin directory under your gcloud installation, e.g.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin.  When prompted to replace the previous copy, type Yes.  This should allow you to run gcloud without being prompted to set CLOUDSDK_PYTHON.

The files are attached in the public bug tracker.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem. I got the same error message.

My Env:  gcloud v274.0.0, Windows 7

[image: Env]

First, I re-installed Google SDK, and changed my path to `\Google\CloudSDK\`.

Second, I got this message

> "\Google\CloudSDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin..\lib\gcloud.py" init" was unexpected at this time."

So I tried to use `cd` command to specific directory where `gcloud.py` is exist.

Finally, I found the path: `\Google\CloudSDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib`, and it works.

Hope it can help you, too.

Answer (score 1):

The problem, or rather bug within the installer, is that you are using a directory that contains spaces within it. At some point of the script the space causes the command to be split up incorrectly, causing the error.

I had the same message and fixed it by re-installing the Google Cloud SDK in a directory without spaces (c:\Google\CloudSDK)